# Determining interior, boundary and closure of a set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Consider the set $X=[-1,1]$ along with a collection $\tau$ of subsets of $X$ such that $U\in \tau$ iff $0\not\in U$ or $(-1,1)\subseteq U$. Note that $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space. Determine the following:

(i) $\overline{(0,1/2)}$.

(ii) $(-1/2,1/2)^o$.

(iii) $\partial (-1,0)$.

I'm not really sure how to do this. Recalling a few definitions though, if $A\subseteq X$ then $\bar{A}=\bigcap_{F\in\mathbb{F}}$ where $\mathbb{F}$ is the set of all closed supersets of $A$. $A^o$, the interior, is the set of all int points (i.e. $x\in X$ such that there exists $O\in\tau$ with $x\in O\subseteq A$.

It doesn't seem obvious how to apply these definitions though.

Comment: Please give it however a try and include your attempts. The interior of $A$ is the largest open subset of $A$ and the closure of $A$ is the smallest closed superset of $A.$ The boundary is the closure minus the interior.

Answer (score 1):

I'll do an alternative to (i) to get you the flavor.

Consider the closure of $A=(-1/3,0)$. If $x\not=0$ then $\{x\}$ is a neighborhood of the point containing no distinct points of $A$, showing $x$ is not a limit point.

As for $0$, every neighborhood of that point contains $(-1,1)$ and in particular a point like $-1/17\in A$. Thus $0$ is a limit point, and the closure of $A$ is $(-1/3,0]$.